# UIViewController's view is too low when navigation bar is opaque

Tags: ios

When I set the `navigationBarHidden` to `NO`, yet I make the navigation bar translucent,  I print the frame when I initialize it with `initWithFrame:`, and it is `{{0, 0}, {320, 504}}`. The view appears beneath the `navigationBar`. Then when I set the navigation bar to not be translucent, with  `[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO]`, I print the frame's view and it's `{{0, 0}, {320, 504}}`. I scaled the iPhone simulator so it's the same size as the actual 4-inch iPhone, and here's a screenshot. You can see the there's now a giant space between the navigation bar and the top of my view, which is red. What's causing the space? The only difference between the two pictures is I've commented out `[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO]` in the first one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your main View frame to [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```